# GitHub secrets scanning - not working as intended

Tags: github, github-secret

I've been attempting to prevent commits that contain hardcoded secrets. I presumed the 'Push Protection' feature under secret scanning would manage this. However, it seems to fall short as I can still push hardcoded secrets without them being blocked. Has anyone had success in resolving this issue? Perhaps, would implementing pre-commit hooks serve as a more effective solution to truly inhibit commits with hardcoded secrets?

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/protecting-pushes-with-secret-scanning

[image]